# How do I use NSLayoutConstraint to make a subview take up remaining/total height of superview

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I have a superview to wich I add two subviews (subview1 and subview2).

I want subview1 to have same width as superview and stretch with superview and also have a height of 30px and align to the top of superview. This I can get working with the following code:

```
NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"height":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:30.0f]};
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(subview1);
NSArray *tabContainerConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[subview1(==height)]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop metrics:metrics views:views];
[superview addConstraints:tabContainerConstraints];

metrics = nil;
tabContainerConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[subview1]|" options:(NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTrailing) metrics:metrics views:views];
[superview addConstraints:tabContainerConstraints];
```

Then I want subview2 to also have same width as superview and stretch with superview and also I want subview2 to align its top to subview1's bottom and then I want subview2 to fill all of the remaining height of superview (align bottom to bottom) and stretch in height with superview. I try to do this with this code:

```
NSDictionary *metrics = nil;
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(subview2);
NSArray *tabContainerConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[subview2]|" options:(NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTrailing) metrics:metrics views:views];
[superview addConstraints:tabContainerConstraints];

views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(subview1, subview2);
tabContainerConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[subview1][subview2]-0-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
[superview addConstraints:tabContainerConstraints];
```

But strange things happens... subview is always aligned to with its top to subview1's bottom and also has the full width of superview so this is good. But height is strange... When first drawn/displayed subview2 has a very limited height, somewhere between 20-30 pixel it seems, but I can force a redraw by switching to another tab/view and back and then it is drawn in full/correct height. My subview2 is a NSTextView, and when I type in text strange things happen, my subview2 suddenly does not take up all height and is no longer aligned with the bottom of superview.

I hope my explanation is ok, if not please ask any question. Any ideas on how to fix this? I thought the |-0-[view]-0-| would do the trick?

Thank you
Søren

Comment: Are you seeing anything in the console? It looks to me like you're creating conflicting constraints with the code above.

Comment: Nothing shows up in the debug console

Comment: @jrturton any wisdom from you I can try out for my problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question whether you're running all of that code or the first snippet is for one view only and the second snippet is for two views.

You should be combining the two VFL strings into one, and you don't need some of the layout options that you are supplying. If you only have one view in the VFL string, the layout options are meaningless.

I'd suggest the following code for creating your constraints:

```
NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"height":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:30.0f]};
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(subview1,subview2);

// Horizontal layout for subview 1
[superview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[subview1]|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];

// Vertical layout - the options here mean that subview2 will be the same width as subview1
[superview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[subview1(==height)][subview2]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllRight metrics:metrics views:views]];
```

You may be having some issues with the intrinsic size of the text view, if it behaves differently when it has content inside it or not. Or, the superview itself may be changing its size - what are the constraints on the superview? You will need to set some borders / background colours or use an introspection tool to determine which frames are going funny.

Comment: Yes I forgot to add some info: subview2 is added to superview (and removed and replaced by another view) dynamically, that is why I add a constraint to subview1 alone/first. Does this change things? I can not add the constrains to subview1 and subview2 at the same time as they are not added to superview at the same time.

Comment: You'd deal with that in a custom `updateConstraints` method on the superview, in that case. In that method, remove all your constraints and then create whatever new ones are necessary for your current subviews. When changing the subviews, call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints:`.

Comment: No thanks, I don't run an email tech support service!

Comment: I'm not an OS X guy but it looks like the problem is with NSTextView - if you replace this with a plain NSView that just draws a flat colour, you're fine. I think you're not supposed to use an NSTextView directly, but to add it to an NSScrollView first, as described here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/TextUILayer/Tasks/TextInScrollView.html and here http://markmail.org/thread/vn6ejxehnfi6yt27 hope that helps!

Comment: Right, I was so focused on the layout stuff. Thank you :)